# Dynamic Updating

Tags: dynamic, scoping

I want to take some points, place them onto a graph and then use the locator pane. I then want to take the new locations that the user has moved the points too and remove the y coordinate and use just the x coordinate and plot that.

I seem to be unable to update datasetx with the point data whatever I do. I have read up on DynamicModule but that hasn't helped. Any recommended reading would be appreciated.

```
DynamicModule[{point1 = {4, 4}, point2 = {4.5, 4.5}, point3 = {5, 5}, point4 = {6, 6}, point5 = {6.5, 6.5}},

{
 dataset = {point1, point2, point3, point4, point5};

 p1 = LocatorPane[Dynamic[dataset], Dynamic[ListPlot[dataset, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}} ]]];

(*just take the x part*) 

 datasetx =   {{point1[[1]],0},{point2[[1]],0},{point3[[1]],0},{point4[[1]], 0},{point5[[1]],0}};

 xgraph = Dynamic[ListPlot[{datasetx}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]];


 GraphicsRow[{{p1}, xgraph}, Dynamic[datasetx]

 }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DynamicModule[
    {point1 = {4, 4}, point2 = {4.5, 4.5}, point3 = {5, 5}, 
     point4 = {6, 6}, point5 = {6.5, 6.5}}, 
   dataset = {point1, point2, point3, point4, point5}; 
   p1 = 
     LocatorPane[
        Dynamic[dataset], 
        Dynamic[ListPlot[dataset, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]]]]; 
GraphicsRow[
  {p1, 
   Dynamic[
     ListPlot[datasetx = dataset /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 0}, 
       PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Algohi's post answers the above question while adhering to the OP's code very closely. I suggest abandoning such adherence for two reasons.

1. Simpler code.
2. Better localization of variables.

Here is what I get by taking Algohi's work as a basis, but simplifying it without worrying about maintaining the structure of the OP's code:

```
DynamicModule[{locators, plot, pts},
  pts = {{4, 4}, {4.5, 4.5}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {6.5, 6.5}};
  locators = 
    LocatorPane[
      Dynamic @ pts, 
      Dynamic @ ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]];
  plot = 
     Dynamic @ 
       ListPlot[pts /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 0},
         PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}];
  GraphicsRow[{locators, plot}, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

The result of evaluating the above code looks and behaves exactly like Algohi's solution.